# How to filter then populate on a separate sheet?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to filter out anything that is below 70% to populate on a separate sheet.

Image of what I am pulling from.
[image]

I looked online and got a little code.

Here is what I have and am running into an error.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

lastrow = Worksheets("sheet1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For r = 2 To lastrow
    If Worksheets("sheet1").Range("O" & r).Value < "70%" Then
        Worksheets("sheet1").Rows(r).Copy

        Worksheets("sheet2").Activate
        lastrowrpt = Worksheets("sheet2").Range("O" & Row.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Worksheets("sheet2").Range("O" & lastrowrpt + 1).Select

        ActiveSheet.Paste

    End If

Next r

End Sub
```

Comment: What is the error and on which line?

Answer (score 0):

This should get you started

In this case you can use the filter and visible cells to copy the range to the other worksheet.

Adjust it to fit your needs

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet
    Dim sourceRange As Range
    Dim sourceFilteredRange As Range

    Dim targetSheet As Worksheet
    Dim targetCell As Range

    Dim cell As Range

    Dim sourceLastRow As Long
    Dim targetLastRow As Long

    ' Define source and target objects
    Set sourceSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set targetSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")

    ' Get last row of source sheet
    sourceLastRow = sourceSheet.Cells(sourceSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    ' Get last row of target sheet
    targetLastRow = targetSheet.Cells(targetSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1

    ' Set source range
    Set sourceRange = sourceSheet.Range("A1:O" & sourceLastRow)

    ' Filter source range by route and shipped
    With sourceRange
        .AutoFilter Field:=15, Criteria1:="<70%"
    End With

    ' Get filtered range
    Set sourceFilteredRange = sourceRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

    ' Copy filtered range to target sheet
    sourceFilteredRange.Copy targetSheet.Range("A" & targetLastRow)

End Sub
```

Let me know if it works

Comment: This works, I would just like for the data that I insert to stay on that page and the filtered data to appear on the next sheet. Would you be able to assist with that? I greatly appreciate the help on this.

Comment: The solution copies the filtered data to the target sheet and leaves the current (source) data as is. Please step through the code using `F8` key and check how it works.